# HTML div collapses only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my website (nucleorental.com).

I found a strange bworser specific behaviour:
If I use Chrome everything works as expected.
In Firefox one div (#home) just collapses and appear like as it is part of the previous div.

I'm not using any browser specific prefix (I'm using prefixfree.js)

It can seem to be a trouble with the bootstrap affix but I disabled affix and the problem remains.

Additionally, if you scroll a down the page the subsequent div's start appearing normal.

[View from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsjgn.jpg)

[View from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgRqk.png)

---

### Solution

I added by mistake an `overflow:hidden` on this specific `<div>`.

So, when the page is just loaded there are only a few horizontal space between the navbar logo and navbar links, and this div get in there.

When the user scrolls, the navbar disappear thanks to the affix plugin, so the div now have all the space it needs and start behaving normally.

You can check an example in this codepen: https://codepen.io/aleritty/pen/oNdvjBw

Comment: Can you describe what the exact issue that you are seeing is? Are we supposed to just scan all the code?

Comment: I'm uploading the images right now, but if you open the website in both browsers you'll see at firsh sight what the problem is

Comment: But, that isn't how to post a question on SO. You should post the code that you are having problems with here.

Comment: Pictures and links aren't very helpful to solving the problem or for making your question useful to future users. Please share a [mcve]. We prefer code.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I really know that this isn't the correct way to post on SO... but really I couldn't find where in the code is the trouble, i just can't see where in the HTML, CSS, or JS could be the cause of this trouble, 

The best way to provide you with the code is linking the website and then I'll edit my answer with the relevant code when found the trouble.

Comment: *"but really I couldn't find where in the code is the trouble"* So, how are we supposed to find it? You should explain the "exact" problem that you see and where you see it.

Comment: @Scott Marcus, but how I'm supposed to explain a visual trouble better than showing it and giving acces to the code by linking it?

Someone spotted the problem at first sight, something that was slipping my attention... It happens.

Comment: In those cases, you should have gotten the images and posted them initially with your question, not after.

Comment: I posted the question while the images was uploading... Sorry if I don't have fiber but just a DSL...
Now this is OT just because the images was missing initially... Ok, I'll deal with it...

Comment: The reason why people want images is that once you have repaired the website you have cited, the question will not be useful to future readers. Questions are intended to be for posterity here.

Comment: posted the question while the images were uploading... it was a minutes matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove overflow:hidden from page class that is along with #home section.

Comment: Wow, that was FAST! I really didn't see that single statement... I also didn't remember when I added that piece! Really Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. You could have also used clear:both to reduce such uncertain behavior.

Comment: @Aleritty if this answer helped, you can press on the check mark to accept it